The most ancient language vs. The oldest language
Is there a difference between the most ancient language and the oldest language? I find that the oldest language is more commonly used in general, but is there a distinction in their meanings?
I found out that ancient can also mean old, so what is the difference between the two of them when referring to the oldest languages?

ancient adjective
1. belonging to a period of history that is thousands of years in the past
2. very old; having existed for a very long time
Oxford Learner's Dictionaries

The Google Ngram chart below shows the frequency of usage between "the oldest language" (red line) and "the most ancient language" (blue line)


Why were dictionary definitions not helpful? What context would you like to use this in? What exactly are you trying to express? As it stands, your question is too broad to produce a useful answer.

@DW256 I don't know if the most ancient language and the oldest language can both describe the language to mean it's old, but why can the oldest language be more widely used than the most ancient language? Can they replace each other?

Note that the definitions mention 'very old', 'thousands of years'. Ancient can only replace old if you are talking about something extremely old. (This can include a language. I don't know of a definitive reason why oldest has replaced most ancient when talking about languages.)

To differentiate these terms, "ancient language" makes me think to a dead language, whilst "old" may mean still living.

As Graffito suggests, the oldest man is a 112 year old living in England, the most ancient man was in Africa 2 million years ago.

It is unclear what motivates your asking specifically about the most ancient language and the oldest language rather than about old and ancient generally. Is there any reason to think that these adjectives work differently when applied to language than they do in other contexts?

To be clear, whatever you call them ancient or old, a language that is currently spoken natively is neither ancient nor old. The preferred adjective for a language that has changed relatively little (compared to another language with the same parent language) is 'conservative'. For example, Italian is more conservative than French because Italian keeps more features of Latin than French.

To differentiate these terms, "ancient language" makes me think to a dead language, whilst "old" may mean still living.
This feeling is well illustrated by @StuartF comment :

The oldest man is a 112 year old living in England.
The most ancient man was in Africa 2 million years ago


There seems little to support this as a distinguishing feature: *"The origins of the Yo-Yo, one of the oldest toys known to humanity, seen on the side of Greek vases 500 BC."" -- https://www.thevintagenews.com/2018/03/03/origins-of-the-yo-yo/ ==  2011 "The clampers produced an ancient tow-truck within a few minutes and removed my car." Independent 31 January (Viewspaper section) 6/2

I don't think that Graffito, or anybody else, is arguing that the two terms are mutually exclusive. On any reasonable interpretation, old is a broader term: all ancient things can also be said to be old, but old encompasses much more. The answer says that '"old" may mean still living', not that it is limited to still living. As for the tow-truck example, the appearance of ancient in it seems to be a playful extension of its core usage.

If there is any difference, (a) it is slight (b) it is concerned with the differences in etymology of "ancient" (from the Norman French = old) and "Old" (from the Germanic ald/eald.
Germanic words, particularly adjectives, have a less formal feel to them.
Edit:
I have been asked by jsw39 to comment, in this answer, on Graffito's comment

To differentiate these terms, "ancient language" makes me think to a dead language, whilst "old" may mean still living. –
Graffito  Commented 2 days ago

and thus
To me, Ancient (Ancient Rome/Ancient Greek) is early classical and pre classical -> BC; "old" (Old English, Old Sarum) is more AD. This does not depend on whethe the language is dead or not.
However "Old" seems to be the umbrella term and the two words are influenced, as always, by the context.
There is the Piraha language that lacks numbers and has no recursive form. This is an ancient language, yet it is still spoken.

Presumably you mean that the difference is slight in this context?

Well, the question is "Is there a difference between the most ancient language and the oldest language?" ...

Graffito has, in a comment, offered a different answer. Do you disagree with it?

@jsw29 As it is a comment, it is not an answer. Graffito has commented on what he thinks of as a difference.

@Greybeard, indeed, this is so, but my question was whether you disagree with it. If you do, as you seem to, it would helpful to those who come to this page in the future to know your reasons (and that has nothing to do with whether what he said is posted as a formal answer).

@Mari-LouA I find your wording most strange - as if I would add to someone else's answer on purpose!

@jsw29 Well, I did respond but unfortunately, I did by editing the wrong question! It has now been removed without trace. This gives me the chance to revise it slightly:  "To me, Ancient (Ancient Rome/Ancient Greek) is early classical and pre classical -> BC; "old" (Old English, Old Sarum) is more AD. However "Old" seems to be the umbrella term and the two words are influenced, as always, by the context."

+1 from me for BC and AD. And I kinda agree with the answer.
